# Vagrant ssh Authentication Failure when normal ssh works

Tags: laravel, authentication, ssh, vagrant, homestead

When I run `vagrant up` to initialize a laravel/homestead box (4.0.0), it keeps saying Authentication Failure: retrying... over and over.

However I can connect normally via ssh `ssh vagrant@127.0.0.1 -p 2222` works just fine.  For some reason homestead didn't copy my `id_rsa.pub` into `authorized_key`, but I just copied it myself, and can log in via normal ssh without a password, but `vagrant up` continues to fail to connect after I reboot the machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved:  I had to modify `app/vendor/laravel/homestead/scripts/homestead.rb` and add the line

```
config.ssh.private_key_path = "/ABSOLUTE/PATH/TO/USER/.ssh/id_rsa"
```

to the file for it to use the proper key, since it wasn't using the key specified in Homestead.yaml.